# Calculating the actual length of fr units

Tags: css, css-grid, specifications

I'm asking here because I suck at maths.

Assuming that the grid size would be 1920px, and I'm not using explicit sizing.

How many fr's would be ie. 1200px ? And how I can calculate it ?

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3.3335fr 1fr;
}
```

The spec says:

> [**12.7.1. Find the Size of an `fr`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-find-fr-size)
>
> This algorithm finds the largest size that an fr unit can be without
>   exceeding the target size. It must be called with a set of grid tracks
>   and some quantity of **space to fill**.
>
> - Let ***leftover space*** be the space to fill minus the base sizes of the
>     non-flexible grid tracks.
> - Let ***flex factor sum*** be the sum of the flex factors of the flexible tracks. If this value is less than 1, set it to 1 instead.
> - Let the ***hypothetical fr size*** be the leftover space divided by the flex factor sum.
> - If the product of the hypothetical fr size and a flexible track’s flex factor is less than the track’s base size, restart this algorithm treating all such tracks as inflexible.
> - Return the hypothetical fr size.

They mean that the "hypothetical fr size" would be for the unit (1fr) ? I guess so

```
1920/(1+3.3335+1) = 359.988750352 <-- The hypothetical fr size
359.988750352 * 3.3335 = 1200.0224993
```

So I guess that's a way to get how many pixels are n fr value.

But, what if I want to do the reverse, which would be the proper way/correct formula to calculate how many fr's would be 1200px ?

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a live example, of what I was doing. The `minmax(min, max)` helped me a lot. I've solved some overflowing errors. And figured out how I can use rem units in grid template tracks but still benefit from shrinking :D

https://codepen.io/jeflopo/pen/OmZBEJ

```css
/**********************************/
/* BODY - THE MAIN GRID CONTAINER */
/**********************************/
/**********************************/
/* DEFINING GRID AREAS            */
/**********************************/
.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.posts {
  grid-area: posts;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

/**********************************/
/* HOW HAS GRID AREAS TO BEHAVE ? */
/**********************************/
/* I'VE LET THEM TO SHRINK TO 0 AND I WILL CONTROL IT WITH MEDIA QUERIES
SETTING `min` of minmax(min, max) to 0 DRASTICALLY PREVENTS THE LAYOUT TO OVERFLOW WHEN RESIZING THE WINDOW.
*/
.header,
.navigation,
.main,
.footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 120rem) 1fr;
}

.main .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 120rem) 30rem;
  grid-template-areas: "posts sidebar";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.main .posts {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.main .sidebar {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/**********************************/
/* CONTENT WRAPPER                */
/**********************************/
/* THESE GRID AREAS (header, main, and footer) OCCUPY FULL TRACKS.
I USE THIS TO CONSTRAINT THE CONTENT OF GRID AREAS TO THE CENTER COLUMN IN THE MAIN GRID. */
.container {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

/******************************************/
/* SOME BASIC STYLING PRESETS             */
/******************************************/
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00f;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  background: #888;
}

.navigation {
  background: #666;
}

.posts {
  background: #f66;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #6f6;
}

.footer {
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__logo">
      <a href="#"><h1>LOGO</h1></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="container">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main class="main" role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="posts">
      <article class="post">
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>This is the body of an article</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <span>SIDEBAR</span>
    </aside>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>FOOTER</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You start off saying you're not using explicit sizing, then asking how to get an explicit size... Otherwise, it's just math. 359.988750352 * y = 1200, solve for y. y = 1200/359.988750352. I'll let you punch that in a calculator.

Comment: I stated this because I'm NOT using explicit sizing (you're lying).  I ask how to obtain the fr equivalence to pixels from a formula, that's a different thing. The 359.988750352 value depends on the leftoverspace / flexfactor sum. But that was this value only because I used 1fr in some of the tracks... If not It must be converted. So I asked if there was a more direct/proper way to get it.

Comment: Hey @Michael_B I've edited the post and published a live example. Since I've solved the problems I had I will not created a new question. Thanks again !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a grid container with 1200px of free space along the X or Y axis (doesn't matter).

If the container has one grid track set to `1fr`, that column / row would consume all 1200px.

If you have `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr`, then  each column would receive an equal distribution of the free space. So each column would be 600px wide, similar to this:

```
grid-template-columns: 600px 600px
```

---

In your case, here's how it works:

[From the spec:](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-find-fr-size)

> It must be called with a set of grid tracks and some quantity of ***space to fill***.

You've called the grid tracks with this rule:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3.3335fr 1fr
```

Your space to fill is 1200px.

---

> 1. Let ***leftover space*** be the space to fill minus the base sizes of the non-flexible grid tracks.

Again, the space to fill ("leftover space") is 1200px.

There are no non-flexible grid tracks. That would be like a column set to 200px:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3.3335fr 200px 1fr
```

The fr algorithm would subtract that 200px track. The remaining space would be available to the fr's.

---

> 2. Let ***flex factor sum*** be the sum of the flex factors of the flexible tracks.

That means we add up the `fr` values:

```
1 + 3.3335 + 1 = 5.3335
```

The flex factor sum is 5.3335.

---

> 3. Let the ***hypothetical fr size*** be the leftover space divided by the flex factor sum.

1200px / 5.3335fr = 225px

---

Now we know that each `fr` unit represents 225px.

- `1fr` = 225px
- `2fr` = 450px
- `3fr` = 675px
- etc...

This means that:

```
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 3.3335fr 1fr
```

is equivalent to:

```
 grid-template-columns: (1fr x 225px) (3.3335fr x 225px) (1fr x 225px)
```

which results in:

```
 grid-template-columns: 225px 750.0375px 225px
```

---

It's important to note, however, that the `fr` unit is not intended to set specific lengths for grid tracks. It's job is to distribute free space in the container (similar to flexbox's `flex-grow`). So your question appears to be a bit theoretical and impractical. If the container is re-sized even slightly, or an inflexible track is thrown into the mix, all pixel calculations above are thrown off.

---

**Update** (based on comment)

> There's an small error. My grid size is 1920px not 1200... But its an extrapolable example. I wanted 3.3335fr relate to 1200px, and not to be the sum of all tracks... 3.3335fr are ~1200px with two adjacent 1fr columns in a grid thats 1920px width.

If the grid container is 1920px wide, then the hypothetical fr size is 360px.

This means that:

```
 grid-template-columns: (1fr x 360px) (3.3335fr x 360px) (1fr x 360px)
```

which results in:

```
 grid-template-columns: 360px 1200px 360px
```

Comment: There's an error. My grid size is `1920px` not `1200px`... But its an extrapolable example. I wanted `3.3335fr` to be `1200px`, and not to be the sum of all tracks. The problem is that this way we should keep trying fr values manually till we get close to the magic number (`1200px`) equivalence. `3.3335fr` are `~1200px` with two adjacent `1fr` columns in a grid thats `1920px` width. I disagree about that the calcs were thrown off... I knew that if I were using non flexible lengths mixed with flexible I must then calculate the leftover space minus the non flexible. And all should be fine.

Comment: Yeah. Its correct. Without rounding decimals it would be 1920/(1+3.3335+1) = 359.988750352

Comment: Maybe, an alternative could be to use `minmax(min,max)` function according to the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-columns-minmax) `max` uses `flex` lengths, it should be `fr`.  So with an html { font-size: 10px; } in theory we could do something like `grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 120rem) 1fr`. If I'm not wrong, this would make the second track initial value to `1200px` expressed through `rem` but using `fr`. What do you think ?

Comment: Your overall layout objective isn't clear in the question. My focus was solely on the calculations. At this point, I would create a live demo and start testing it out.

Comment: I was considering to add some code with live preview or a code pen. Just give me some time. What I'm doing is a Fullwidth header layout, with a centered container for header and main content... footer is also fullwidth. using a 3x3 main grid for all.

Comment: *If I'm not wrong, this would make the second track initial value to `1200px` expressed through `rem` but using `fr`.* I don't think that's correct. It would make the second track initial value equal to the content size (`auto`), and the maximum width would be `120rem`. This means that the second track could theoretically have a 0 width (if there's no content) and the two `1fr` columns could take 50/50 of the container.

Comment: Well... For `min` parameter `auto` is the default. That's right. But we could also set a fixed minimum in `rem`. Whilst the maximum could be `120rem`. I'm unsure if css converts the max to `fr` or `rem`.

Comment: Sounds like we're on to a different question now. Consider accepting this question and posting a new one with your live demo.

Comment: Did it. Thanks a ton for your help :) I'll update again with a link to the new question ;)